# Compare 4 or more columns values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like:

```
ID   A0  A1  A2 A3 A4
14   A   B   A  C  A
15   A   A   A  A  A
```

I need to compare all 5 columns and check if they have same value and retrive the only one that have all same values....in this case the one with ID 15.
Is there a way to accomplish that in T-SQL?

Answer (score 12):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server's brand of 
SQL, but it must be something like:

```
SELECT ID FROM My_Table 
WHERE 
(A0 = A1) AND
(A1 = A2) AND
(A2 = A3) AND
(A3 = A4);
```

Check out this [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b1bbb9cce70b59809a31e28a7f1e76d) which shows all the answers in the answer thread.

Answer (score 11):

Given the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Data
(
    ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    A0 character(1) NULL,
    A1 character(1) NULL,
    A2 character(1) NULL,
    A3 character(1) NULL,
    A4 character(1) NULL
);

INSERT dbo.Data
    (ID, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4)
VALUES
    (14, 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A'),
    (15, 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A');
```

An alternative way to compare all non-ID columns for equality is:

```
SELECT
    D.*
FROM dbo.Data AS D
WHERE EXISTS
(
    -- All columns except the last one
    SELECT D.A0, D.A1, D.A2, D.A3
    INTERSECT
    -- All columns except the first one
    SELECT D.A1, D.A2, D.A3, D.A4
);
```

If there are many columns, this may be easier to write than a query with multiple `AND` clauses (and will often be more compact). In Management Studio, you can [drag the Columns node from Object Explorer](http://dattatreysindol.com/2012/06/08/tips-n-tricks-ssms-quickest-way-to-select-and-query-all-columns-from-a-table-in-sql-server/) to a text window to generate a comma-separated column list. Offsetting that list for the second part of the `INTERSECT` is trivial as well.

The execution plan generated by this query is just as efficient as the multiple `AND` clause version. Semantically, it is slightly different in that `NULL` data items will compare equal to each other.

[image: Execution plan]

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest another solution. You can use `COMPUTED COLUMN`. Of course this is if you can modify table structure and if you will do that comparison very often.

Inside the `COMPUTED COLUMN` you can calculate if all columns that you need to compare contains the same data with `boolean value`. After that you only compare that value in your queries.

Also if you set `persistent option` the value will be calculated and stored each time you change data. In that case there will be storage overhead.

About `COMPUTED COLUMNS` you can read for example [here](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-computed-column-calculated-column-sample.aspx)

**EDIT:** 
As [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race) and [Ian Ringrose](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/767/ian-ringrose) remarked - if there is an `filtered index` on `COMPUTED COLUMN` (in that case it must be `persistent`) you can benefit performance. Of course there must be enough amount of data.

Comment: +1 for this. It could be very useful if columns A0 - A4 aren't/can't be indexed - the query might be much faster.

Comment: 10x, @Vérace. I don't think about that kind of application.

Comment: This is only of benefit if COMPUTED COLUMN is indexed, a filtered index on SQL server works great for this.   (Only index rows where the column is 1)

Comment: Yes, @Ian Ringrose, of course.

Comment: I cannot modify the table structure...any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

Another example using cross apply. The idea is to transpose a0, a1, ..., to rows and then check where max and min equals:

```
select d.id 
from dbo.data as d
cross apply ( values (d.a0),(d.a1),(d.a2),(d.a3),(d.a4) ) as x(a)
group by d.id
having min(a) = max(a);
```